# Canvas not drawing Android

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I have been trying to start a new project and when I went to start up I couldn't get anything working. I have looked at the code for the past few hours and played with it but I can't remember how I fixed this last time it happened.

```
package org.waldev.canvascollisiontest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class CollisionTest extends Activity {
private Panel game;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    game = new Panel(this);
    setContentView(game);
}

public class Panel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{
    Threads thread;

    public Panel(Context context) {
        super(context);
        thread = new Threads(this.getHolder(), this);
        setFocusable(true);
    }

    public void onDraw(Canvas c)
    {
        c.drawColor(Color.BLUE);
    }
    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    //when the game starts, run the thread\
    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        holder.setFormat(PixelFormat.RGB_565);
        thread.setRunning(true);
        thread.start();
    }

    //if its destroyed, then destroy the thread
    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        boolean retry = true;
        thread.setRunning(false);
        while (retry) {
            try {
                thread.join();
                //                  bitmaps.recycleAll();
                retry = false;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // we will try it again and again...
            }
        }
    }

}
}
```

And the thread:

```
package org.waldev.canvascollisiontest;

import org.waldev.canvascollisiontest.CollisionTest.Panel;

import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;

public class Threads extends Thread{
SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
private Panel game;

private Canvas c;
private boolean isRunning = true;

// desired fps
private final static int    MAX_FPS = 24;
// maximum number of frames to be skipped
private final static int    MAX_FRAME_SKIPS = 0;
// the frame period
private final static int    FRAME_PERIOD = 1000 / MAX_FPS;  


public Threads(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, Panel panel){
    this.surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
    game = panel;
}

public void setRunning(boolean run){
    isRunning = run;
}

public boolean getRunning(){
    return isRunning();
}

public SurfaceHolder getSurface(){
    return surfaceHolder;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    Canvas canvas;

    long beginTime;     // the time when the cycle begun
    long timeDiff;      // the time it took for the cycle to execute
    int sleepTime;      // ms to sleep (<0 if we're behind)
    int framesSkipped;  // number of frames being skipped 
    boolean updated = false;

    sleepTime = 0;

    while (isRunning) {
        canvas = null;
        try {
            canvas = this.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
            synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
                beginTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                framesSkipped = 0;
                if(canvas != null)
                {
                    game.onDraw(canvas);
                }
                timeDiff = System.currentTimeMillis() - beginTime;
                sleepTime = (int)(FRAME_PERIOD - timeDiff);

                if (sleepTime > 0) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
                }
                else
                {
                    updated = false;
                }
            }
        } finally {
            // in case of an exception the surface is not left in
            // an inconsistent state
            if (canvas != null) {
                surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        }   // end finally
    }
}
public boolean isRunning() {
    return isRunning;
}
}
```

I threw some break points in there and it is never calling surfaceCreated in CollisionTest. I know it has to be something stupid that I am missing here, so if you see it let me know. Thanks!

William

Comment: Your synchronized block can not possibly be helping. You already are calling lockCanvas() -- That does the synchronization for you. BTW, surfaceview is double buffered, so you'll need to redraw the state on every frame to avoid flickering. Also, if that thread is interrupted, you should break out of the while loop. Don't just roll over that exception. Use a break; statement.

Comment: Alright...I will have to work on it...both of these I copied from another project that works. I am just trying to get it to draw the color again, and I know the thread works when used correctly, I just can't figure out why it isn't being called, which I am guessing I forgot to so something in the surfaceview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working, I forgot to add the:

```
getHolder().addCallback(this);
```

to the Constructor for Panel, which is what was causing it to not work. Thanks!

Comment: Psst.  Mark your answer as the answer.